# how to show-up my own Recipe on cloudify appCatalog tab for clodify v2.7

Tags: cloudify

In Cloudify V2.7, After installing my own receipe, I am not able to see that receipe in App Catalog tab.How can we show up the receipe in App Catalog?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a recipe to be displayed in the application catalog (i.e. : in the Cloudify web UI), 
you need to place it in a public online repository and configure it in your unzipped Cloudify distribution file.

However, when you install a recipe (not via the app catalog) it is not displayed in the application catalog.

More info about the Cloudify recipes catalog can be found here : 
http://getcloudify.org/guide/2.7/setup/recipes_tab.html

HTH,
Tamir.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer!

Your suggestion helped me.

I have one more question, how to uninstall a recipe from Cloudify WebUI